# R - Mediated moderation in lavaan

Tags: r, lavaan

I'm trying to set up a mediated moderation model using lavaan but am unsure how to code it. I want to replicate [Hayes process model number 7](https://docplayer.net/408084-Model-templates-for-process-for-spss-and-sas-c-2013-2015-andrew-f-hayes-and-the-guilford-press-model-1-conceptual-diagram-statistical-diagram.html), but with two independent variables and an interaction between them. The independent variables are dummy coded, so I don't think I can just multiply them together to get the interaction term. But the moderator, mediator, and outcome variables are continuous.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame( iv1 = c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50)),
                  iv2 = c(rep(c(0,1), 50)),
                  moderator = rnorm(mean = 5.19, n = 100, sd = 1.22),
                  mediator = rnorm(mean = 4.02, n = 100, sd = 1.90)
                  dv = rnorm(mean = 3.27, n = 100, sd = 1.35))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, you can just multiply the binary predictors together. The 0 and 1 are logical parameters, and multiplying in this case preserves the logical relation. You will create a new 0-1 variable which will correctly represent the interaction. Sometimes it really is that easy.